# Difference between Microsoft test frameworks

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, .net-core

I would like to know the key differences between `MSTest.TestFramework` and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework`

In my experience, I did find out that `MSTest.TestFramework` is the default for default for .net core unit tests but seems possible to use in dotnet Standard as well

`Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework` seems to be the default for dotnet Standard.

Other than that are there any other differences?

Comment: It seems that they are the same thing : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/mstest-update-to-mstestv2?view=vs-2022#old-style-csproj-example